# How to use facebook login in parse.com backend on website?

Tags: javascript, facebook, parse-platform, web, facebook-login

I am trying to integrate parse database with my website. It is almost one day I spent but I couldn't figure out the problem. Here is my code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

    Parse.initialize("**************************", "**********************");

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
            appId      : '*****************', 
            cookie     : true, 
            xfbml      : true
        });
        Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, {
            success: function(user) {
                if (!user.existed()) {
                    alert("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                } else {
                    alert("User logged in through Facebook!");
                }
            },
            error: function(user, error) {
                alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
            }
        });
    };

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=920929871279093";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="3" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="true" data-auto-logout-link="true"></div>
```

My problem is that when I run this piece of code I get following error but login button appears and work fine.

[image]

As I search for this issue people are saying I change

```
//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=920929871279093";
```

To

```
//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml;
```

or

```
//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.all;
```

I do not understand how this really work. And appreciate if anyone say where I am calling init.FB twice and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put version number in init function:
The following is the example from parse.com https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#users-setup

```
<script>
  // Initialize Parse
  Parse.initialize("$PARSE_APPLICATION_ID", "$PARSE_JAVASCRIPT_KEY");

      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    Parse.FacebookUtils.init({ // this line replaces FB.init({
      appId      : '{facebook-app-id}', // Facebook App ID
      status     : true,  // check Facebook Login status
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow Parse to access the session
      xfbml      : true,  // initialize Facebook social plugins on the page
      version    : 'v2.3' // point to the latest Facebook Graph API version
    });

        // Run code after the Facebook SDK is loaded.
  };

      (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```